# Jenkins unable to install plugin unknownhost

Tags: docker, jenkins, centos, unknown-host

I have installed Oracle VM and created a centos 7 machine
in which I have installed Docker successfully

then I installed jenkins from docker image : jenkins/jenkins

in that I am not able to install plugins, it is giving me below error:
java.net.UnknownHostException: mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn

I have reinstalled couple of times but the problem still exists.

I tried to ping google in jenkins container and that is working fine.

Please help me out here.

Comment: Have you tried  install plugins again? Pinged the mirror? Tried [another mirror](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/status.html)?

Comment: Yes I installed so many times again, installed on other PC as well but showing the same result. How can I change to other mirror please?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for this. The mirror was not working for my system due to network level restriction. After removing that it is working fine now.